# Xdocument, get each element(s) value

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I have xml as follows:

```xml
<Reports>
  <report>
    <name>By Book</name>
    <report_type>book</report_type>
    <Object>Count Change</Object>
    <Slicers detail="detail">
      <Namespace>EOD</Namespace>
      <BookNode>HighLevel</BookNode>
      <DateFrom>T-2</DateFrom>
      <DateTo>T-1</DateTo>
      <System>NewSystem</System>
    </Slicers>
  </report>
</Reports>
```

I simply want to loop through the value of each element of the Xdocument (pref would be any element under Slicers) but to start with just all elements.

When I run the following:

```
        var slicers = from c in config.Elements("Reports")
                      select c.Value ;

        foreach (var xe in slicers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(xe);
        }
```

The output is a single line concatenating all the values together.

"By BookbookCount ChangeEODHighLevelT-2T-1NewSystem"

I want to loop through them one at a time, 'By Book' first, run some code then book etc etc.

I am sure this is simple, but cant get round it. I have tried foreach(Xelement in query) but same resulst

Comment: That is because you are just printing the value of the root node (which is everything in it). Try going through the descendands

Comment: can you example that for me? I have tried the following with same results `var slicers = from c in config.Descendants("Reports")
                          select c.Value;`

Answer (score -1):

i would do it something like this;

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
//load in your xml here
XmlNodeList xnList = doc.SelectNodes("nodeYou'reLookingFor");
//for getting just the splicers you could do "Reports/report/Slicers"

foreach (XmlNode node in xnList)
    string namespace = node["Namespace"].InnerText;
    //go through all your nodes here
```

you're creating a xmldoc, loading your xml into it, creating a list which holds each node in the list (at a specified Xpath), and then looping through each. in the loop you can do whatever you want by referencing

```
 node["nodenamehere"].InnerText
```